# Tripod Quick Release Video Pin Dimensions

Tags: video, hardware

I have an Industrial camera that I am working with and I want to mount it to a standard tripod that features a quick release with video pin; otherwise known as an anti rotation pin. While I wait for the tripod to be delivered, I'm designing an adapter to mount it and I would like to also include a hole for the anti rotation pin.

The Issue I need help with is figuring out the diameter, protrusion height and distance between centers of the video pin and the 1/4-20 mounting screw. Another Problem is I can't figure out if the video pin is fore or aft of the 1/4-20 screw. Does anyone have such a drawing or can take measurements? I've already spent two hours looking for this and can't find a single drawing calling out that pin.